# JVM high virtual memory on SUSe 12 vs SuSe 11

Tags: jvm

Running this simple Java program on our SLES12 systems reserves 4GB of virtual memory:

```
class Test {  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(100000);    
  }
}
```

I was able to reduce it to 1GB using these flags:

```
java -Xmx1m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=5m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=5m -Xss228k -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=1m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1k Test
```

Still, on our SLES11 system (with the same amount of memory) this takes only 200M. I've checked all memory pools with jconsole and nothing big stands up. Both are running with OpenJDK 8.0.202. Any idea how to avoid this memory reservation?

Comment: 1. Try [NativeMemoryTracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html). 2. Don't bother - virtual memory is kind of "infinite" on 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 3):

I used windows 10 and java 1.8.0_201. I run this application with yours parameters and **-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary** paremeter, I got the result as below:

> Native Memory Tracking:
>
> Total: reserved=49889KB, committed=38613KB

Reserved memory represents the total amount of memory our app can potentially use. Conversely, the committed memory is equal to the amount of memory our app is using right now.
Java 8 uses Parallel GC as the default gc. So I added **-XX:+UseSerialGC** paremeter for change default GC algorithm and I got the result as below:

> Native Memory Tracking:
>
> Total: reserved=29565KB, committed=18349KB

Because class, thread, internal and gc committed area decreased. You can find necessary informations in [oracle docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html#BABGFJDJ)
JIT compilers has threads and these threads occupy the area. I used **-XX:CICompilerCount=1** and **-XX:-TieredCompilation** for trimming the number of compiler threads down. The result is :

> Native Memory Tracking:
>
> Total: reserved=27481KB, committed=16265KB

** ***I do not recommend you do the following. This is not quarentee, may crash unexpectedly. Only I am trying to answer question. *** **

I trimming down the stack size for VM threads with "-XX:VMThreadStackSize=256" parameter. Result is

> Total: reserved=25177KB, committed=13961KB

Result: We decrease comitted area from 38613KB to 13961KB and reserved area from 49889KB to 25177KB with these parameters.

**Note: I focused memory reservation. I didn't consider application performance.**

Comment: Thank you! I've use these flags:

/usr/intel/pkgs/openjdk/8.0.202/bin/java -Xmx1m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=5m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=5m -Xss228k -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=1m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1k -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:VMThreadStackSize=256 -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary Test 

and managed to get the VM down to 638M - still trying to reduce it further...

the thing is that native memory tracking shows much less:

Total: reserved=25067KB, committed=13955KB


so looks like it doesn't account for the entire used VM

Comment: I think you should not try to reduce used memory it any further. Jvm may crash unexpectedly. Already jvm running minimum level now.

Comment: Generally this makes sense but this is a small client app so I'm less concerned about crashes and more of the fact that 100-200 different users are running the client on the same machine, eating up the VM reservation on the machine